# What is the $H^{-1}$ metric?

Tags: functional-analysis, riemannian-geometry

I have a source (Recent Developments in Topological Hydrodynamics by Boris Khesin) which talks about the $H^{-1}$ metric on the space $C^\infty(S^1, \text{SO}(3))$. As per my own research, the $H^k$ metric generally refers to
$$\left(\sum_{i=0}^k \int \left|f^{(i)}\right|^2\text{d} x\right)^{1/2}.$$

where $f^{(i)}$ is the $i$th derivative of the function $f$, and $\left|\cdot\right|$ is inherited from the metric on the target space (in this case $\text{SO}(3)$).

However, I do not see how this would be generalized to a negative coefficient $k$. I considered interpreting the $-1$th derivative as a primitive function but this has two problems.

1. The primitive function will have an arbitrary constant which means I would need some way of picking this constant;
2. $S^1$ is not simply connected, so a primitive function may not even exist.

That being said, what metric *does* $H^{-1}$ refer to?

Comment: I think my tags for the question may not be perfectly accurate. If anyone has suggestions for better tags, please add/remove the tags. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: $H^{-1}$ usually refers to the dual space of $H^1_0$.

Comment: What does the subscript $0$ on the $H$ refer to? Compact support?

Comment: Zero boundary values in the sense of traces. You can also identify the space $H^1_0(\Omega)$ as the closure of $C_c^\infty(\Omega)$ in the $H^1(\Omega)$-norm.